# #ckan Data Explorer

Tags: ckan

I have CKAN 2.7.3 on my Ubuntu 16.04. My Datapusher and Datastore are working. My problem is my data is not loading even though it is already uploaded in the datastore.

[image]

Data explorer is not working.

[image]

I enabled those data preview on my development.ini file. What seems to be the problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Choose manage and in view tab you can create a new view for your data manually, but in case you will want views to be created automatically you will need to define some of the default views plugins in your .ini file e.g:

> ckan.views.default_views = recline_view pdf_view geojson_view

For more information check [docs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/data-viewer.html#defining-views-to-appear-by-default)